# Eliminar filas con todo 0

Tags: r

Parto de un df

```
   df <- read.table(text = '
           id X1 X2 X3
      1  0  0  0
      2  0  0  1
      3  0 NA  0
      4  0  0  0
      5  0  1  1
      6  0  0  0
      7  0  0  1', header = TRUE)
```

Quiero eliminar aquellas filas que tengan todos los datos 0. Si es desconocido no se elimina.

```
filter(df, X1 != 0 | is.na(X1) | X2!= 0 | is.na(X2) | X3 != 0 | is.na(X3) )


  id X1 X2 X3
  2  0  0  1
  3  0 NA  0
  5  0  1  1
  7  0  0  1
```

Pero cuando tengo 100 columnas con nombres diferentes ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma bastante simple:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    sum = sum(c_across(X1:X3) != 0)
  ) %>% 
  filter(sum != 0)
```

- `c_across(X1:X3)`: Usada en combinación con `rowwise()` retorna un vector con las columnas seleccionada. Lo que hacemos es sumar aquellas columnas que no sea 0
- Luego simplemente es cuestión de filtrar, si todas las columnas son 0 o `NA` efectivamente la suma de todas debería ser 0.

Comment: Quiero quedarme con los que no son 0  y con la fila que tiene NA.   %>% 
  filter(sum != 0 | is.na(sum)) %>%
  select(-sum)

Comment: `sum != 0` debería contemplar ya los casos de NA y cualquier otro valor distinto de 0.